# Calculator in HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css, calculator

I am new to Javascript and HTML. I have written code for a calculator, so review my code and points out pros and cons in it.

```js
(function ($) {
    var shiftflag = 0;
    var fontreducer = 0;

    $.fn.close = function () {
        $("#dragging").remove();
    };
    $.fn.calc = function () {
        this.remove();
        $("body").append('<div id="dragging"><FORM NAME="calc" id="rocorners2"><TABLE BORDER=none id="calfields"><TR><TD><INPUT TYPE="text" id="inputarea"  NAME="input" Size="16" autofocus><br><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one" class="calcinput" VALUE="1" ><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two"   class="calcinput" VALUE="2" ><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" class="calcinput" VALUE="3"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus"  class="calcinput" VALUE="+" ><br><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four"  class="calcinput" VALUE="4" ><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five"  class="calcinput" VALUE="5"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six"   class="calcinput" VALUE="6" ><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="minus" class="calcinput" VALUE="-"><br><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" class="calcinput" VALUE="7"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" class="calcinput" VALUE="8"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine"  class="calcinput" VALUE="9"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="times" class="calcinput" VALUE="*"><br><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" class="calcinput" VALUE="c"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero"  class="calcinput" VALUE="0"><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt"  class="calcinput" VALUE="="><INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="div"   class="calcinput" VALUE="/"><br></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM></div>');
        $("#dragging").draggable();
        var finding = (document).getElementById("inputarea");
        finding.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); {
            currentfontsize = parseFloat($("#inputarea").css('font-size'));
            $(".calcinput").click(function () {
                var res = $(this).val();
                var flag = 0;

                if (res === 'c') {
                    flag = 1;
                    calc.input.value = "0";
                }
                if (res === '=') {
                    var c = eval(calc.input.value);
                    var text = document.getElementById("inputarea");
                    text.value = c;
                } else {
                    if (calc.input.value == 0) {
                        calc.input.value = res;

                    } else
                        calc.input.value += res;
                }
                if (flag === 1) {
                    calc.input.value = '0';
                }
                currentfontsize = parseFloat($("#inputarea").css('font-size'));
                funcc();
            });
            $("#calfields").keydown(function (e) {
                var b = e.keyCode;
                currentfontsize = parseFloat($("#inputarea").css('font-size'));
                if (b === 13 || b === 187) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var c = eval(calc.input.value);
                    var text = document.getElementById("inputarea");
                    text.value = c;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("inputarea").style.fontSize = 34;
                }
                if (b === 16) {
                    shiftflag = 1;
                }
                if (b === 187 && shiftflag === 1) {
                    calc.input.value += '+';
                    e.preventDefault();
                    shiftflag = 0;
                } else if (((b > 64 && b < 91) || (b === 192) || (b > 218 && b < 222))) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                funcc();
            });
//This function is to reduce the font size if there is any overflow in the text box area
            function funcc() {
                console.log(($('#inputarea')[0].scrollWidth > $('#inputarea').innerWidth()));
                console.log(currentfontsize);
                if (($('#inputarea')[0].scrollWidth > $('#inputarea').innerWidth())) {
                    if (fontreducer === 0 || currentfontsize === 34) {
                        currentfontsize = currentfontsize - 5;
                        fontreducer = 1;
                    } else if (fontreducer == 1 && currentfontsize > 13) {
                        currentfontsize = currentfontsize - 2;
                    } else if (currentfontsize < 13)
                        currentfontsize = currentfontsize + 0;
                    $("#inputarea").css({
                        'font-size': currentfontsize
                    });
                }
                return;
            };
        };
    }
}(window.jQuery));

function manipulate_and_display(arr, operator) {
    var loop;
    var str = "";
    if (arr[0] === undefined) {
        calc.input.value = "";
    } else {
        for (loop = 0; loop < arr.length - 1; loop++) {
            str = "" + str + "" + arr[loop] + "" + operator + "";
        }
        str = str + "" + arr[arr.length - 1];
        calc.input.value = eval(str);
    }
}
```

```css
 table {
     cell-padding border: 0px;
     cell-spacing border: 0px;
     border-color: darkgrey;
     color: 2px solid green;
 }
 
 .calcinput {
     height: 50px;
     font-size: 22px;
     width: 50px;
     color: black;
     padding: 2px;
     background-color: rgb(229, 236, 197);
     border-radius: 0px;
 }
 
 #ruler {
     visibility: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
 
 #inputarea {
     text-align: left;
     bottom: 20px;
     height: 40px;
     font-size: 34px;
     width: 200px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     overflow: scroll;
 }
 
 #dragging {
     border: 2px solid green;
     width: 210px;
     height: 267px;
 }
 
 #rocorners2 {
     margin-top: 20px;
 }
 
 #calfields {
     border: 1px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="calc.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="calc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Calculator</h3>
    <input type=button Name="display" value="Calculator" id="initialise">
    <input type=button name="Close" value="close Calc" id="closing_the_calc">
    <span id="ruler"></span>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#initialise").click(function () {
            var arr = new Array();
            arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            $("#initialise").calc();
// If we pass the array with values it can do the specified operation by the operator you have passed and display it in the text box of calculator.
            manipulate_and_display(arr, '*');
        });
        $("#closing_the_calc").click(function () {
            $("#closing_the_calc").close();
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HTML

`script` elements are not allowed before the `html` or after the `body` element (neither are any other elements for the matter) . Depending on how the scripts are written, they belong all inside the `head` element, or preferably at the end of (but inside) the `body` element.

All script should be in external files. So either out the "document ready" code also into `calc.js`, or put it (together with the function `manipulate_and_display`) into a separate file.

## JavaScript

### `manipulate_and_display`

What exactly is the point of `manipulate_and_display`? It's name doesn't expain what it does and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the calculator directly.

The variable `calc` in it isn't defined anywhere I can find, but It works, so currently I'm assuming it's an implicit variable created by giving the calculator form the name "calc". Don't do that. Using implicit variables created from element IDs and names an out-of-date way to access them. Always get element references using DOM methods such as `getElementById()` (or store them when creating elements and reuse the references).

You unnecessarily use empty strings when concatinating. This:

```
str = "" + str + "" + arr[loop] + "" + operator + "";
```

could just as well be:

```
str = str + arr[loop] + operator;
```

### Plugin

The whole point of (jQuery) plugins is, that you can reuse the elements and used them in different pages, possibly even multiple times in the same web page. However you by doing things such as hardcoding IDs and having variables such as `shiftflag` in a higher scope so it can only exist once.

Speaking of `shiftflag`: Don't use `0`/ `1` to represent booleans.

Defining a (separate) plugin with a generic name such as `close` will overwrite (or be overwritten by) any other plugin that happens to have the same name.

In plugins you should allways assume that the jQuery object references multiple elements. You should either make sure it only contains one element, or better write your plugin so that it supports multiple elements by using `jQuery.each()`.

Generally check out jQuery's tutorial for basic plugin development: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

*(There is much more, but I don't have the time right now. Maybe I can come back later.)*